# Template Specialization Based Upon is_pointer Trait

Tags: c++, c++11

I am sure this has been answered before however, I am not sure what the correct terminology/wording of my question is.

Take the following example class:

```
class Fooable {
public:
    int foo(int a);
};
```

I want to write a template class that can call the foo() method of any generic type regardless if it is a pointer type or a reference as such:

```
template <typename T>
class FooableCaller {
public:
    void useFooWithSomeContext(?) {
        //This method needs to use the foo() method of some Fooable to
        int a = _getA();
        int b; //Returned from foo()

        //Depends on if the Fooable passed as an argument is a pointer or reference type
        //b = fooable.foo(a);
        //b = fooable->foo(a);

        _doWork(b);
    }
private:
    int _getA();
    void _doWork(int a);
};

int main() {
    Fooable f1;
    std::shared_ptr<Fooable> f2 = std::make_shared<Fooable>();

    //If I want to call foo() of f1, I have to do f1.foo();
    //If I want to call foo() of f2, I have to do f2->foo();
    //What is the correct want to write FooableCaller so that useFooWithSomeContext is select to use either . or -> depending on if T is reference or a pointer?

    FooableCaller<?> fc1;
    FooableCaller<?> fc2;

    fc1.useFooWithSomeContext(f1);
    fc2.useFooWithSomeContext(f2);
}
```

Is this a good place to use the std::is_pointer trait?  And, if yes, how do I use it properly?

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Does `callFoo` need to be in a `FooableCaller` class? It seems like it could just be a free function.

Comment: @cigien This is just a simple example. In my actual code, callFoo does a little bit more work so I needs to be within a class.

Comment: Ok. Can you also add an example of how you would use the class and the function? Would `FooableCaller` be constructed with `f1` and `f2`?

Comment: Please also show what you would write in `main`.

Comment: What standard are you using? In C++17 you could use `constexpr if` instead of template specialization.

Comment: @flowit I believe my compiler only supports up to C++11

Comment: Now I'm confused about why `FooableCaller` is a template at all. It seems like you would want `callFoo` to be a template.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? https://godbolt.org/z/Md3ndqbqz

Comment: @PatrickRoberts This seems to work well for me! I understand what the decltype, and std::is_same statements are doing. Could you example how the rest of this declaration works? Is that extra typename out front template specialization?  Could you post this as an answer with explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good place to use the `std::is_pointer` trait?

Not exactly, though a trait would help. [`std::is_pointer`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) determines whether a type is a cv-qualified raw pointer or not, whereas your example uses the type `std::shared_ptr`, a pointer-like container type. You can start by defining your own trait to detect the appropriate `operator*` on the type:

```cpp
template <typename Ptr, typename T>
using is_pointer_like_of = std::is_same<decltype(*std::declval<Ptr>()), T&>;
```

Then you can use this trait with [`std::enable_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) to define the [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae)-friendly template method below:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class FooableCaller {
public:
    void callFoo(T& fooable) {
        // do a little more work
        fooable.foo();
    }

    template <typename Ptr>
    typename std::enable_if<is_pointer_like_of<Ptr, T>::value>::type callFoo(Ptr p) {
        callFoo(*p);
    }
};
```

The `typename` specifier is necessary to indicate that the [dependent name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name) `::type` is a member typedef of `std::enable_if<...>`, namely `void`, rather than a member value.

Finally, you can use `FooableCaller` like this:

```cpp
int main() {
    Fooable f1;
    std::shared_ptr<Fooable> f2 = std::make_shared<Fooable>();
    FooableCaller<Fooable> fooableCaller;

    fooableCaller.callFoo(f1);
    fooableCaller.callFoo(f2);
}
```